# C++ non-type template parameter compile time check

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, non-type

I have a C++ class with two non-type template parameters:

A dimension of type size_t and a const reference to a vector of objects.

```
template <size_t DIMENSION, const std::vector<Tuple>& BORDERS>
class Rule {
public:

  Rule(const std::vector<Tuple>& ranges, const Action& action) :
      ranges_(ranges),
      action_(action) {};

private:

  std::vector<Tuple> ranges_;
  Action action_;
};
```

Is there a possibility to ensure at compile time that the following condition holds?

```
DIMENSION == BORDERS.size()
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: static_assert(DIMENSION == BORDERS.size(), "Sizes don't match");

Comment: I don't think std::vector& can be used as a constant expression, and even if it does (because the compiler will treat it like a pointer perhaps?), its members and state cannot be used as such

Comment: @Asaf references can be used as non-type template parameters just as shown in the example. I'm pretty sure though it won't work like Sven expects.

Comment: @ArneMertz even so, .size() is a runtime function which depends on the runtime state of the vector object

Answer (score 1):

A `vector` is a dynamic container, so its size depends on how you use it at run-time. Unfortunately that means there is no compile-time check you can do to achieve what you want.

`std::array` may be more suitable in this case, as its size is fixed at compile time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I am not sure how to integrate std::array into the above code, as I have to specify the size of the array as a template parameter.

Comment: It's actually very simple. `std::array` takes the size as a template parameter too. For example, to get an array of 5 ints, you declare: `std::array<int, 5>`. In your example above, you'd just do: `std::array<Tuple, DIMENSION>`. (As a side note, there's no need to use the container itself as a template parameter. Just the size is fine.)